# Is the space $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ complete and what is its category?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, baire-category

Let $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}=\{(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}: x_n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ with the Fréchet metric $d(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{-n}\dfrac{|x_n-y_n|}{1+|x_n-y_n|}$

a) Is the space $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ complete? If not, find its completion.

b) What is the category of $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ in $\omega$? Here $\omega$ is the space of all real sequences equipped with $d$.

Here is my attempt:

The space $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ with the Fréchet metric is complete. That is, for $\forall \varepsilon  \enspace k \in \mathbb{N} \enspace \exists N  :m,n\ge N$

\begin{align}
d(x_{m},x_n)&<{\varepsilon\over2^k(\varepsilon+1)}\\
\sum_{j=1}^\infty{|x_{m,j}-x_{n,j}|\over2^{j}[1+|x_{m,j}-x_{n,j}|]}&<{\varepsilon\over2^k(\varepsilon+1)}\\
 {|x_{m,k}-x_{n,k}|\over2^{k}[1+|x_{m,k}-x_{n,k}|]}&<{\varepsilon\over2^k(\varepsilon+1)}\\
 |x_{m,k}-x_{n,k}|&<\varepsilon 
\end{align}

Therefore we conclude that $x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\omega$ and $(\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}},d)$ is a complete metric space.

b) By Baire's theorem, if $(\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}},d)$ is a complete metric space, it implies that if of the $2^{\text{nd}}$ category in itself, hence it is also of $2^{\text{nd}}$ category in $\omega$.

Is my reasoning correct? I am not quite sure about the category part, especially. Thanks.

Comment: How does your proof of completeness show that every Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$ converges, which is what completeness means?

Comment: Well, in Fréchet metric we have coordinatewise convergence, so I thought it is valid for every other $x_n$. I couldn't find any counterexample. I am new to real analysis, sorry.

Comment: If a subspace is of second category in itself, it needn't be of the second category in the ambient space. The subspace $\mathbb{R}\times \{0\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is of the second category in itself, but it is nowhere dense, hence of the first category, in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The space $\omega$ ($\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$) is complete in this Fréchet metric. This is well-known. $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ is closed in it (product of closed sets is closed; the Fréchet metric induces the product topology), and hence it is also complete in that metric.

It's also clear that $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ is nowhere dense in $\omega=\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ (as it contains no (product) open set at all, so has empty interior), so is first category in the ambient space, despite being second category in itself (cf. a line in the plane, which is a nowhere dense closed copy of a complete metric space too; it happens a lot).